# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'password'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-cloud-datastore

I want to create a functional login form using flask web framework. I am using Google Datastore. Currently, I am getting the following error.

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'password'`

Also, I am not sure about the `id` attribute I've used in the User Model. May be the server does not recognize id's for each user. Kind of confused. Any help is appreciated.

my models.py file in view:

```
import datetime

from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class User(ndb.Model):
    id = ndb.StringProperty()
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    password = ndb.StringProperty()
    joined_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty() 
    updated_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty() 
    is_admin = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)

    # Flask-Login integration
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return false

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id
```

forms.py file:

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    username  = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, g, flash, render_template, url_for, redirect
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user
import models
import forms

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = forms.LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = models.User.exists(username = form.username.data)
        except models.DoesNotExist:
            flash("Your email does not match", "error")
        else:
            if user.password == form.password.data:
                login_user(user)
                flash("You've been logged in!", "success")
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
            else:
                flash("Your password does not match!", "error")
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently just checking weather username exists or not. You have to fetch that entity first then check username and password. This will solve your problem.

```
user_check = User.query(User.username == form.username.data).get()

    if user_check:
        if user_check.password == form.password.data:
            print "Success"
        else:
            print "Wrong Password"
    else:
        print "No Username Exists"
```

Comment: After implementing the code in the login view, I logged in using username, and password; however, after that attempt, it is showing `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'`